# Create a cluster inside a VPC using AWS Step Functions

Tags: amazon-emr, aws-step-functions

I am trying to create an EMR cluster inside my VPC using existing security settings copied from the EMR clusters I am building via the CLI in a Jenkins job.

I cannot get this to work. If I don't specify ec2-attributes it fails (and is trying to create the cluster outside of my VPC which is not what I want). If I do include them it fails. Eithe way it *tries* to start the cluster (so I think the IAM stuff is OK):

```
The field "Ec2InstanceAttributes" is not supported by Step Functions
```

Here is the config I am trying to use:

> ```
> "Create_A_Cluster": {
> ```

```
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:createCluster.sync",
  "Parameters": {
    "Name": "WorkflowCluster",
    "VisibleToAllUsers": true,
    "ReleaseLabel": "emr-6.0.0",
    "Applications": [
      {
        "Name": "Hive"
      }
    ],
    "Ec2InstanceAttributes": {
        "Ec2KeyName": "URMOM",
        "Ec2SubnetId": "subnet-4543b1f",
        "RequestedEc2SubnetIds": [
            "subnet-1235cb1f"
        ],
        "Ec2AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
        "RequestedEc2AvailabilityZones": [],
        "IamInstanceProfile": "emr-ec2-role-sexy-dev",
        "EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup": "sg-669e32158412f98b6",
        "EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup": "sg-2169f6e0142047ed1",
        "ServiceAccessSecurityGroup": "sg-04d4a4db4cac4c1d7",
        "AdditionalMasterSecurityGroups": [],
        "AdditionalSlaveSecurityGroups": []
    },
    "ServiceRole": "emr-service-role-sexy-dev",
    "JobFlowRole": "emr-ec2-role-sexy-dev",
    "LogUri": "s3n://emr-logs-sexy-dev/logs/sexy/dev/",
    "Instances": {
      "KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps": true,
      "InstanceFleets": [
        {
          "InstanceFleetType": "CORE",
          "TargetOnDemandCapacity": 2,
          "TargetSpotCapacity": 0,
          "LaunchSpecifications": {},
          "InstanceTypeConfigs": [
            {
              "WeightedCapacity": 4,
              "EbsConfiguration": {
                "EbsBlockDeviceConfigs": [
                  {
                    "VolumeSpecification": {
                      "SizeInGB": 32,
                      "VolumeType": "gp2"
                    },
                    "VolumesPerInstance": 2
                  }
                ]
              },
              "BidPriceAsPercentageOfOnDemandPrice": 100,
              "InstanceType": "m5.xlarge"
            }
          ],
          "Name": "Core - 2"
        },
        {
          "InstanceFleetType": "MASTER",
          "TargetOnDemandCapacity": 1,
          "TargetSpotCapacity": 0,
          "LaunchSpecifications": {},
          "InstanceTypeConfigs": [
            {
              "WeightedCapacity": 1,
              "EbsConfiguration": {
                "EbsBlockDeviceConfigs": [
                  {
                    "VolumeSpecification": {
                      "SizeInGB": 32,
                      "VolumeType": "gp2"
                    },
                    "VolumesPerInstance": 2
                  }
                ]
              },
              "BidPriceAsPercentageOfOnDemandPrice": 100,
              "InstanceType": "m5.xlarge"
            }
          ],
          "Name": "Master - 1"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much experience running EMR but I do have exposure with Step functions. The documentation for the target API in your case doesn't have "Ec2InstanceAttributes" as a parameter. It's contents is somewhat scattered in other fields e.g. Instances.

I'd suggest trying to align to the specs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/APIReference/API_RunJobFlow.html

Answer (score 0):

For folks who may find this via a web search, I was able to do this by specifying an *Ec2SubnetId* as child of *Instances* and it was built into the VPC as desired.